# Angular-UI run dropdownToggle from ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Is there any way to run dropdownToggle from ng-click directive ?
I am using it with ngMobile to avoid delayed click of "Actions" button on touch devices.

```
  <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle">
        Actions
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a>Action 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Action 2</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

There is also a problem with menu, which doesn't close on tap if I don't keep the Action1/Action2
pressed for a long time. (much longer than usual tap).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I found a solution (not the best one I assume) but it works.
If someone has a better one, please share.

Opening a dropdown adds an "open" class to the dropdown element, so in order to get it opened on using ng-click I needed to add this class.

I know it's a temporary solution but didn't find the better one.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-class="{open: opened}" ng-click="opened=!opened"  ng-init="opened=false">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle">
        Actions
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a ng-click="$location.path('/some/addr')">Action 1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

As for closing menu on click: this could be caused by error in my html (not properly closing some tag). After correction, problem disappeared. From source I see that dropDown menu is closed on both click & running `$location.path()`

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem when dropdown form doesn't close on `$location.path(newPath)` My solution is, if you use uncompressed ui-bootstrap file, in

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.dropdownToggle', [])
    .directive('dropdownToggle', ['$document', '$location', function($document, $location)
```

Change

```
scope.$watch('$location.path', function() {
    closeMenu();
});
```

To

```
scope.$watch('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    closeMenu();
});
```

Comment: Seems like new angularjs 1.2.0rc1 (released today) makes ngClick emit a "click" event also.. so that would solve the problem. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Shouldn't be scope.$on() instead of $watch ?